# Uncontrollable Scrolling in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7

Here's my issue (two examples of it):

Windows lists which are longer than the list box (e.g. Favourites) scroll upwards uncontrollably as soon as the mouse cursor moves over the list box.
When I open a Windows edit box (e.g a Find edit box) that have pre-populated contents, the cursor moves left towards the beginning of the box. Also it's impossible to enter any data because the data enters literally backwards - e.g. if I type in "complete", it enters as "etelpmoc".
Okay, so I figured there was a problem with either my mouse or my keyboard. I swapped these out for others (another keyboard and a wired rather than a wireless mouse). No change. I started the computer up in safe mode. No change. I downloaded the latest drivers for both the mouse (wired and unwired) and the keyboard. No change.

I'm using Windows 7 Professional, and I'm flummoxed!

Can anybody help? I don't want to have to rebuild my computer!

Comment: Looks like a virus program to me. Do an antivirus scan with updated definition files first?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I've been away.   A virus was the first thing I suspected, although it's an unusual kind of virus.  Virus scans from two different anti-virus systems tell me that there's nothing there.

Comment: Do you see any suspecious processes in the task manager in safe mode that are not OS processes? Some viruses can fake this too still you might want to check.Also the list of startup programs. I have never seen a device driver or regional setting causing such bizarre behaviour, i don't think those can do this

Comment: inspect your processes in task manager try remember some weird program you install from the internet (try to remember the last program you install or open before this happen) I would highly suggest for you to format your window for safety reason there might be a spyware in your system also

Comment: Sorry, this post is three years old.   In the end I had to rebuild the computer.   A pain in the neck, but it did get rid of the problem.    Thanks to those of you who relied.